# How to update many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

tl;dr: I have some database with a many-to-many relationship. When I edit its data and call `SaveChanges()`, nothing is being changed in the database.

Full Question:

I encountered a really strange problem. I want to update a many-to-many relationship, but it doesn't want to change.

My Models look like this (I've posted only this part that is important in this question):

```
public class Note
{
    public Note()
    {
        NoteTags = new HashSet<NoteTag>()
    }

    public int NoteId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; }
    [...]
}

public class NoteTag
{
    public int NoteId { get; set; }
    public Note Note { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public Tag()
    {
        NoteTags = new HashSet<NoteTag>();
    }

    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

What I do to update this db relationship:

Get the current state of `Note` from the database:

```
Note noteInDb = db.Notes.Include(x => x.NoteTags).ThenInclude(x => x.Tag).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.NoteId == note.NoteId);
```

Clear `List<NoteTags>` and add a new one:

```
noteInDb.NoteTags = new List<NoteTag>();
noteInDb = TagsToAddToTags(note);
```

What `TagsToAddToTags` does: it finds proper `Tags` in the database and adds them to the `List<>` like that:

```
note.NoteTags.Add(new NoteTag { Tag = tagInDb });
```

Then I tell the database that I've modified some data and save it:

```
db.Entry(noteInDb).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The `noteInDb` variable looks exactly how I want it to look when I'm saving it to the database. **Unfortunately nothing is being saved, and when I view the database, it still looks the same as before.**

The weird fact is also that when I write this line just after SaveChanges():

```
Note noteInDb2 = db.Notes.Include(x=>x.NoteTags).ThenInclude(x=>x.Tag).FirstOrDefault(x => x.NoteId == note.NoteId);
```

I can see that `noteInDb2` has 9 `NoteTag`s (it has 4 of them before, and I wanted it to have 5, so this is in fact sum of what was before and what I wanted to add). But when I go to LINQPad to see what it really looks like, it shows me 4 old `NoteTag`s (no changes).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension I made to remove the unselected items and add the newly selected items to the list:

```
public static void TryUpdateManyToMany<T, TKey>(this DbContext db, IEnumerable<T> currentItems, IEnumerable<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> getKey) where T : class
{
    db.Set<T>().RemoveRange(currentItems.Except(newItems, getKey));
    db.Set<T>().AddRange(newItems.Except(currentItems, getKey));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKeyFunc)
{
    return items
        .GroupJoin(other, getKeyFunc, getKeyFunc, (item, tempItems) => new { item, tempItems })
        .SelectMany(t => t.tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, temp) => new { t, temp })
        .Where(t => ReferenceEquals(null, t.temp) || t.temp.Equals(default(T)))
        .Select(t => t.t.item);
}
```

Using it looks like this:

```
var model = db.Notes
    .Include(x => x.NoteTags)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.NoteId == note.NoteId);

db.TryUpdateManyToMany(model.NoteTags, listOfNewTagIds
.Select(x => new NoteTag
{
    TagId = x,
    NoteId = note.NoteId
}), x => x.TagId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move your code around.  Since you retrieve data using AsNoTracking you changes are not tracked until you set the state of the entity as modified.  So before you call TagsToAddToTags, call db.Entry(noteInDb).State = EntityState.Modified;

Comment: well, it still doesn't work. Can I somehow check what data Entity Framework is going to change when I call SaveChanges? Do EF keep somewhere the queries that are being done to database? It would help a lot, because I don't know what EF is exactly doing when I call SaveChanges()

Comment: You could trace queries by adding tracing provider, but you could just as easily trace them in SQL Server profiler.  You could check the state of entities after  you add them , which is probably the best starting point.  db.Entry(newNoteTag).State just before you fire save changes.